# Meaning of 6.3.1.1p2, bullet point 2

Tags: c, language-lawyer, bit-fields

[6.3.1.1p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2) says

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.

What's the intention behind the second bullet point?

Why leave out integer fields of other types whose rank is less than that of `int`?

Does it mean that I can do e.g.:

```
printf("%d\n", (struct{ _Bool x:1; }){0}.x);
```

but not:

```
printf("%d\n", (struct{ unsigned short x:1; }){0}.x);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably this is because of [6.7.2.1p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p5):

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted.

I.e. you can't portably create bit-fields of other types anyway.